# Node js : How to access local variable between the methods

Tags: node.js

```
first();
function first(){
    second();
    third();
}
function second(){
    var b='second';
}
function third(){
    console.log(b);
}
```

Getting error while trying to access variable b in third(), can you please help
 console.log(b);
             ^

ReferenceError: b is not defined

Comment: You might want to read [What is the scope of variables in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to access `b` than you have to define it as global

```
    first();
 var b;
  function first(){
     second();
    third();
 }
function second(){
     b='second';
}
function third(){
    console.log(b);
}

console.log(b);
```

look my bin [global b](https://jsbin.com/dazanid/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: thank  you, it is working fine.